# How to forward declare third-party struct

Tags: c++

In my original code, I refer to the third-party .H in the `ClassOne` header file and everything works fine. Now, I received a new requirement that doesn't allow me to refer to the third-party .H in the `ClassOne` header file. So that the consumer of my code (i.e. ClassOne) will not have to indirectly includes the third-party .H file. I have tried the following modification but it doesn't work.

Here is the sample code:

```
// third_party.h
struct PPP
{
    int x;
    int y;
}; // without default constructor

// Original code!
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// ClassOne.h // my class
#include <third_party.h> // refer to the .H in header file
namespace X
{
    class ClassOne
    {
    ...

    private:
        boost::scoped_ptr<PPP> m_scpPPP;    
    };
}
// ClassOne.cpp
#include <third_party.h>
namespace X
{
    ClassOne::ClassOne()
    {
        m_scpPPP.reset( new PPP() ); // fine
    }
    ...
}

// Modified code!
==========================================================
// ClassOne.h
struct PPP; // error C2371: 'PPP' : redefinition; different basic types
namespace X
{
    class ClassOne
    {
    ...

    private:
        boost::scoped_ptr<PPP> m_scpPPP;    
    };
}

// ClassOne.cpp
#include <third_party.h>
namespace X
{
    ClassOne::ClassOne()
    {
        m_scpPPP.reset( new PPP() ); // now see errors. 
        // error C2512: 'PPP' : no appropriate default constructor available
    }
    ...
}
```

Question 1> Where should I forward declare the third-party struct type `PPP`?

Question 2> Why the compiler now complain about the PPP that has no default constructor?

Comment: I end up using Pimpl Idiom to solve my problems. Simply put, I add a new wrapper class (i.e. ClassOneWrapper) that is designed to encapsulate the third-party class ClassOne and then ONLY include the third-party library in .CPP file while forward declare the new ClassOneWrapper in .H and leave the detail for CPP file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not standard behavior to instantiate templates with incomplete types, therefore it shouldn't work `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Having said that, `unique_ptr` has a special rule, allowing to take incomplete types. If you use it (instead of `boost::scoped_ptr`), then it is done like this :

```
// forward declaration of PPP, assuming c++ header
struct PPP;

namespace X
{

    class ClassOne
    {
    ...

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<PPP> m_scpPPP;    
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: That won't work. Since you use PPP (and not PPP*) in side your ClassOne, the compiler needs to know the size at that point, so it *needs* to know the definition of PPP. To hide PPP from the public .h file, you'll have to do more. One possible solution is to hide your implementation class behind another class. Another would be only to refer to PPP* in your class declaration (although that would make the usage of scoped_ptr<> a bit pointless).

The compiler expects a default constructor because he assumes there is one. He needs the definition of the class to call "new" as well. You can work around this problem by moving the implementation of the ctor to the .cpp file, where you *may* include thirdParty.h.

Comment: "Since you use PPP (and not PPP*) in side your ClassOne, the compiler needs to know the size at that point, so it needs to know the definition of PPP." `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` uses `T` only to declare pointers `T*` and references `T&`, so the size shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ok, didn't know these details, so this might not be the problem then.